# Siri app suggestions not working properly on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, siri

I have an iPhone XR running iOS 16.5. I have Siri suggestions turned on for apps.

If I swipe down from my home screen, I get eight app suggestions which are partly based on what I’ve used most recently. I’ve found lately that sometimes when I tap the icon of one of these eight apps it opens one of the other seven.

- Which of the other seven it opens seems to be random; I haven’t detected a pattern yet.
- This happens when I tap the icon of any app, which includes both Apple apps and third-party apps.
- This only happens with Siri app suggestions; tapping an icon in my home screen, in the dock or in the app chooser always opens the correct app.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This is more of an experiment than a possible solution. In the Siri & Search settings, you can switch Suggest App on or off for each individual app. If you switch them all off except two, so only two apps are suggested, do you still reproduce the issue? If not, try increasing the number and see what happens.

Comment: Will try over the next couple of days and let you know.